# linux device driver container_of macro when using arrays

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver

In one of the legacy device driver that I am using, I have a structure format as below -

```
struct inner_struct_containing_cdev {
   struct cdev cdev;
   ....
   ....
   /* more variables */
};

struct outer_struct {
    /* because I need 10 devices */
    struct inner_struct_containing_cdev inner[10];
    ....
    ....
    /* more variables which are common to all the 10 devices. */
};
```

Now in my init_module I am calling `alloc_chrdev_region` and other allocation related calls. Now in my `open` file operation with signature `int open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)` I can get access to the cdev structure and hence the `inner_struct_containing_cdev`. But I would like to get the pointer to `outer_struct` instead. In the `open` call I don't know which array index of the `inner_struct_containing_cdev` struct I received a pointer to. 
Is it possible to use `container_of` macro in such a case? Or need to re-design the structures?

Currently I am handling the situation using a global variable. But this prevents me from having multiple instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `container_of` to go from `inner_struct_containing_cdev` to `outer_struct`; you've stated the reason yourself, you don't know which index of the array you're looking at.

You need to organize your data structure like this instead:

```
 struct driver_instance {
    /* variables shared among all N devices go here */
 };

 struct device_instance {
    struct cdev cdev;
    /* variables particular to only one device */
    struct driver_instance *driver;
 };
```

You only use `container_of` to go from the `cdev` to the `device_instance`; then you dereference the `driver` pointer to get the `driver_instance`.  You allocate a `driver_instance` when your driver is initialized, and then when it spins up individual devices it makes each point to that object.  Use the core kernel's reference counting logic to know when to deallocate them.

In addition to the fact that this, y'know, *works*, it means you don't have to hardwire the number of devices at compile time.